# Is it necessary to lift the state up when passing data to parent component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm working on my react native project, and I think I made a big mistake. I have a `DaySelector` component that has a `Day` child. Their purpose is to create a multi-select bar that shows every day in the week. This is the code:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Button, Alert } from "react-native";
import { TouchableOpacity } from "react-native-gesture-handler";
import colors from "../assets/constants/style-variables";

interface Item {
  selected: Boolean;
  day: String;
}

function Day(props) {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={props.onPress}
      style={props.selected ? styles.buttonActive : styles.button}
    >
      <Text>{props.day}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
}

export default class DaySelector extends React.Component<
  {},
  { selectedItems: undefined | Item[]; items: Item[] }
> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectedItems: [],
      items: [
        {
          selected: false,
          day: "Lu",
        },
        {
          selected: false,
          day: "Ma",
        },
        {
          selected: false,
          day: "Mi",
        },
        {
          selected: false,
          day: "Ju",
        },
        {
          selected: false,
          day: "Vi",
        },
        {
          selected: false,
          day: "Sa",
        },
        {
          selected: false,
          day: "Do",
        },
      ],
    };
  }

  onPress = (index) => {
    let items = [...this.state.items];
    let item = { ...items[index] };
    item.selected = !item.selected;
    items[index] = item;
    this.setState({ items });
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      selectedItems: prevState.items.filter((i) => i.selected),
    }));
  };

  onCompleteSelection = () => {
    console.log(this.state.selectedItems);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          {this.state.items.map((item, index) => {
            return (
              <Day
                key={index}
                selected={item.selected}
                day={item.day}
                onPress={this.onPress.bind(this, index)}
              />
            );
          })}
        </View>
        <Button title={"Check"} onPress={this.onCompleteSelection} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flexDirection: "row",
  },
  button: {
    margin: 5,
    borderColor: colors.lightGray,
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderRadius: 40,
    padding: 7,
  },
  buttonActive: {
    margin: 5,
    borderColor: colors.primary,
    borderWidth: 2,
    backgroundColor: colors.primary,
    borderRadius: 50,
    padding: 7,
  },
});
```

It works very nicely, grabs the data and logs it in the console. But the problem is that I integrate this component in another "form" where the user has to choose not only the days of the week but also some schedule stuff. I need to put a "next" button that sumbits the data grabbed by all of my components.

My biggest is that the only thing I can think of is lifting the state up, which would be very complicated, since the parent component is a functional one:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useMutation } from "@apollo/react-hooks";
import { REGISTER } from "../Queries";
import Loader from "../components/Loader";
import DateTimePicker from "@react-native-community/datetimepicker";
import { View, Button, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import colors from "../assets/constants/style-variables";
import { TouchableOpacity } from "react-native-gesture-handler";
import PrimaryText from "../assets/constants/PrimaryText";
import DaySelector from "../components/DaySelector";

export default function ScheduleSelect({ navigation, route }) {
  const [loadingRegistration, setLoadingRegistration] = useState(null);

  const [showTimePicker1, setShowTimePicker1] = useState(false);
  const [showTimePicker2, setShowTimePicker2] = useState(false);

  const [time1, setTime1] = useState(null);
  const [time2, setTime2] = useState(null);


  const show1 = () => {
    setShowTimePicker1(true);
  };

  const show2 = () => {
    setShowTimePicker2(true);
  };

  const handleTimePick1 = (event, selectedTime) => {
    setShowTimePicker1(false);
    if (selectedTime !== undefined) {
      setTime1(selectedTime);
    }
  };

  const handleTimePick2 = (event, selectedTime) => {
    setShowTimePicker2(false);
    if (selectedTime !== undefined) {
      setTime2(selectedTime);
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <PrimaryText fontSize={20} margin={22} textAlign={"center"}>
        Recibirás turnos en estos horarios:
      </PrimaryText>
      <View style={styles.cardHolder}>
        <View style={styles.card}>
          <View style={styles.timeHelper}>
            <PrimaryText textAlign={"center"}>Desde</PrimaryText>
          </View>
          {time1 && (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={show1}>
              <View style={styles.timeSelected}>
                <PrimaryText textAlign={"center"} fontSize={36}>
                  {`${time1?.getHours()}:${
                    time1.getMinutes() < 10
                      ? "0" + time1.getMinutes()
                      : time1.getMinutes()
                  }`}
                </PrimaryText>
              </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          )}
          {!time1 && (
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={show1}>
              <PrimaryText fontSize={36} letterSpacing={2} textAlign={"center"}>
                --:--
              </PrimaryText>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          )}
          {showTimePicker1 && (
            <DateTimePicker
              value={new Date()}
              testID="dateTimePicker"
              mode={"time"}
              is24Hour={true}
              display="default"
              onChange={handleTimePick1}
            />
          )}
        </View>
        <PrimaryText fontSize={36} margin={7}>
          -
        </PrimaryText>
        <View style={styles.card}>
          <View style={styles.timeHelper}>
            <PrimaryText textAlign={"center"}>Hasta</PrimaryText>
          </View>
          {time2 && (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={show2}>
              <View style={styles.timeSelected}>
                <PrimaryText textAlign={"center"} fontSize={36}>
                  {`${time2?.getHours()}:${
                    time2.getMinutes() < 10
                      ? "0" + time2.getMinutes()
                      : time2.getMinutes()
                  }`}
                </PrimaryText>
              </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          )}
          {!time2 && (
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={show2}>
              <PrimaryText fontSize={36} letterSpacing={2} textAlign={"center"}>
                --:--
              </PrimaryText>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          )}
          {showTimePicker2 && (
            <DateTimePicker
              value={new Date()}
              testID="dateTimePicker"
              mode={"time"}
              is24Hour={true}
              display="default"
              onChange={handleTimePick2}
            />
          )}
        </View>
      </View>
      {time2?.getTime() < time1?.getTime() && (
        <PrimaryText color={colors.warning}>
          Por favor, seleccioná horarios válidos
        </PrimaryText>
      )}
      <PrimaryText margin={5}> Los días: </PrimaryText>
      <View style={styles.card}>
        <DaySelector />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  button: {
    padding: 7,
  },
  card: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "center",
    backgroundColor: colors.iceWhite,
    borderRadius: 10,
    padding: 20,
    marginBottom: 10,
    shadowColor: "#000",
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 0,
      height: 2,
    },
    shadowOpacity: 0.25,
    shadowRadius: 3.84,
    elevation: 5,
  },
  cardHolder: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  timeHelper: {
    justifyContent: "center",
    position: "absolute",
    marginTop: 5,
  },
  timeSelected: {
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  editIcon: {
    right: 3,
    top: 3,
    position: "absolute",
  },
});
```

As you can see, it's a very large component and, even worse, i'd have to make it either a class component or try to translate everything to a functional one. Is there any way of avoiding lifting the state up and just passing the data over to the parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a callback function and pass it to your `DaySelector` component so you can store the value in the parent state

In your parent

```
const handleChange = (value) => {
  setDay(value);
}
<DaySelector onChange={handleChange} />
```

In your child

```
onCompleteSelection = () => {
  this.props.onChange(this.state.selectedItems);
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will try it later!